# Error in mounted hook: "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'required')" in vuejs

Tags: vue.js

in my laravel vue application I have following vue modal to upload a document

```
<template>
<div>
    <modal-md :identifier="identifier" :has-multiple-actions="false">
        
        <template slot="modal_title">
            <div class="flex justify-between items-center border-b border-certstyle-border px-10 py-3">
                            <h3 class="text-2xl leading-10 text-certstyle-titles font-bold my-2 flex items-center">
                                <span class="border-l-2 border-certstyle-orange inline-block h-6 mr-2"></span>
                                <span>Add document</span>
                            </h3>
                            <div class="h-full flex items-center cs--reveal transition-all duration-500"></div>
                        </div>
        </template>
        <template slot="modal_content">
            <!--Modal content-->
            <div class="bg-certstyle-background-light w-full h-full px-10 pt-8 pb-10">
            <!--Name-->
           <div class="mb-5 relative z-30">
                                    <p class="text-certstyle-titles font-bold text-sm mb-1">Name</p>

                                    <div class="h-12 relative z-10">
                                        <input  value="" name="name" id="add_name_input" type="text" class=" form-input w-full relative z-10" >
                                    </div>

                                    <validator identifier="addDocument" name="add_name_input" selector="id" ></validator>
            </div>

            <div class="flex justify-between">

                <!--Completed at-->
                <div class="w-1/2 mr-2">
                    <p class="text-certstyle-titles font-bold text-sm mb-1">Date of issue</p>
                    <validator-v2 identifier="addDocument"  name="issued_at" :rules="{ required: { message: 'Date of issue is required.'}}">
                        <div class="h-12">
                            <cs-date-picker
                                id="minimumDate"
                                v-model="dateOfIssue"
                                :default-selection="true"
                                name="issued_at">
                            </cs-date-picker>
                        </div>
                    </validator-v2>
                </div>

                <!--Expiration date-->
                <div class="w-1/2 ml-2">
                    <p class="text-certstyle-titles font-bold text-sm mb-1">Expiry date</p>
                    <validator-v2 identifier="addDocument" name="expires_at" depends-on-name="does_not_expire"  :rules="{ required: { message: 'Expiry date is required.'}}">
                        <div class="h-12">
                            <cs-date-picker
                                id="maximumDate"
                                v-model="expiryDate"
                                :default-selection="true"
                                :disable="doesNotExpire"
                                name="expires_at">
                            </cs-date-picker>
                        </div>
                    </validator-v2>
                </div>

            </div>
            <div class="flex justify-between">

                <!--Completed at-->
                <div class="w-1/2 mr-2">
                    <div class="mb-4">
                        <label class="inline-flex items-center focus:outline-none checkbox--container mt-2">
                            <input type="checkbox" name="does_not_expire" v-model="doesNotExpire">
                            <span class="checkbox--checkmark flex items-center justify-center ">
                                                    <svg class="icon text-certstyle-orange feather feather-check" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round">
                                                        <polyline points="20 6 9 17 4 12"></polyline>
                                                    </svg>
                                                </span>
                            <span style="bottom: 4px;" class="text-certstyle-text font-normal text-sm relative">This document does not expire</span>
                        </label>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>

            <!--Upload document-->
            <div class="mb-1">
                <dashboard-input-label identifier="document" :settings="{help: true, helpDirection: 'left'}">
                    Upload document
                    <template slot="helpText">
                        Maximum filesize is 5 MB.
                        The default allowed file extensions are: pdf, jpeg and png.
                    </template>
                </dashboard-input-label>
                <validator-v2 :identifier="identifier" name="document_file" :rules="{ required: { message: 'Document is required.'}}">
                    <custom-file-upload :max-upload-file-size="5" name="document_file" v-model="documentFile" ref="documentDocument"></custom-file-upload>
                </validator-v2>
            </div>

            <!--Document number-->
            <div class="mb-1">
                <p class="inline-block text-certstyle-titles font-bold text-sm mb-1">Document Number</p>
                <div class="relative">
                    <input  v-model="documentNumber" name="document_number" id="add_document_number_input" :disabled="doesNotHaveDocumentNumber" type="text" class=" form-input w-full relative z-10" >
                    <input-annotation identifier="document_number">
                        Fill in your document number here.
                        <span class="font-bold"> Note!</span>
                        Use the document number mentioned on the qualification you upload. Don\'t use your WINDA-ID.

                    </input-annotation>
                    <label class="inline-flex items-center focus:outline-none checkbox--container mt-2">
                        <input type="checkbox" name="no_document_number" v-model="doesNotHaveDocumentNumber">
                        <span class="checkbox--checkmark flex items-center justify-center">
                                                    <svg class="icon text-certstyle-orange feather feather-check" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round">
                                                        <polyline points="20 6 9 17 4 12"></polyline>
                                                    </svg>
                                                </span>
                        <span style="bottom: 4px;" class="text-certstyle-text font-normal text-sm relative">
                            This document has no document number.
                        </span>
                    </label>
                </div>
            </div>

            
            </div>
        </template>
        <template slot="modal_actions">
            <div class="flex items-center justify-between space-x-4">
                <disables-submit-on-errors
                    :identifier="identifier"
                    @proceed="addNewDocument"
                >
                    <loading-button ref="submitBtnSave" size="normal">
                        Save & Close
                    </loading-button>
                </disables-submit-on-errors>
                <disables-submit-on-errors
                    :identifier="identifier"
                    @proceed="storeDocumentAndAddNew"
                >
                    <loading-button ref="submitBtn" size="normal">
                        Save & Add new
                    </loading-button>
                </disables-submit-on-errors>
            </div>

        </template>
    </modal-md>
    <div class="flex flex-col fixed top-0 right-0 z-50">
        <toastr-alert
            v-if="message !== ''"
            :message="message"
            :type="type"
            @hidden="resetToastrMessage">
        </toastr-alert>
    </div>
</div>
</template>

<script>
import ModalMd from "@/components/dashboard/sharedComponents/modals/modal-md";
import CheckboxWarning from "@/components/inputs/checkbox-warning/checkbox-warning";
import CsDataPicker from "@/components/inputs/cs-data-picker/cs-data-picker";
import HasToastrMessage from "@/Mixins/HasToastrMessage";
import Helper from "@/Support/Helper";

var url = window.location.href;
var url_split = url.split("/");
var emp_id_location = url_split.length - 2;
var emp_id = url_split[emp_id_location];

export default {
    name: "add-document",

    props: ['identifier', 'selectedDocumentId'],

    mixins: [HasToastrMessage],

    components: {CsDataPicker, CheckboxWarning, ModalMd},

    data() {
        return {
            certificadocumentId: null,
            dateOfIssue: null,
            expiryDate: null,
            documentNumber: null,
            doesNotHaveDocumentNumber: false,
            doesNotExpire: false,
            documentFile: null,
            doesOptIn: false,
            isAddNew: false,
        }
    },

    watch: {
        doesNotHaveDocumentNumber() {
            if(this.doesNotHaveDocumentNumber) {
                this.documentNumber = null
            }
        }
    },

    mounted() {
        if(this.selectedDocumentId) {
            this.documentId = this.selectedDocumentId
        }
    },

    methods: {
        addDocument(documentId) {
            this.documentId = documentId
        },

        storeDocumentAndAddNew() {
            this.isAddNew = true
            const loader = this.$refs.submitBtn;
            this.storeDocument(loader)
        },

        addNewDocument() {
            const loader = this.$refs.submitBtnSave;
            this.storeDocument(loader)
        },

        storeDocument(loader) {
            loader.startLoading();

            if(!this.documentNumber && !this.doesNotHaveDocumentNumber) {
                this.showToastrErrorMessage("Document number is required unless you confirm it does not apply")
                loader.stopLoading();
                return
            }

            if(!this.expiryDate && !this.doesNotExpire) {
                this.showToastrErrorMessage("Expiry date is required unless you confirm it does not apply")
                loader.stopLoading();
                return
            }

            const formData = new FormData()
            formData.append('emp_id', emp_id)
            formData.append('issued_at', moment(this.dateOfIssue).format('DD-MM-YYYY'))
            formData.append('expires_at', moment(this.expiryDate).format('DD-MM-YYYY'))
            formData.append('document_number',  !this.doesNotHaveDocumentNumber
                ? this.documentNumber
                : null)

            if(this.doesNotExpire) {
                formData.append('does_not_expire', this.doesNotExpire)
            }

            formData.append('opt_in', this.doesOptIn)
            formData.append('document_file',this.$refs.documentDocument.file)


            this.$store.dispatch('addDocument', formData).then((data) => {
                this.showToastrSuccessMessage("Document added successfully")

                if(!this.isAddNew) {
                    eventsHub.$emit(`overlay:close:${this.identifier}`)
                }

                this.reset()
                this.$emit('created')
            }).catch((error) => {
                if(Helper.isset(error.response.data) &&Helper.isset(error.response.data.errors)) {
                    collect(error.response.data.errors).each((error) => {
                        this.showToastrErrorMessage(error[0])
                    });
                }
            }).finally(() => { loader.stopLoading()})
        },

        reset() {
            this.documentNumber = null
            this.doesNotHaveDocumentNumber =  false
            this.doesNotExpire =  false
            this.documentFile = null
            this.doesOptIn = false
            this.isAddNew = false
        },
    }
}
</script>

<style scoped>

</style>
```

but when I run this, it gives me an console error saying, **Error in mounted hook: "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'required')"**

I'm using the same code for another model and it works fine, and apart from the console error once when I hit the submit, it's just showing me the loading spinner, without saving the data to db

What's I'm doing wrong and how to fix it?

Comment: it could be a bug in vue, there is an open issue on this error: https://github.com/vuejs/core/issues/5657